# "insert data out of date range" error in psql while inserting data

Tags: postgresql

I'm getting the following error while inserting the data in my postgres database table.

> Error:  ERROR:   insert data out of date range

query:

```
 insert into schema.table (file_name) values ('my_ref_file_121323_1562070973_0.dmp');
```

table:

```
|Column                 |           Type           |
|file_name              | character varying(100)   |
```

Comment: There must be something else going on.  Neither of those columns are dates.  Is there a trigger on the table?  Are there additional columns?

Comment: Hi Ranjith. I've tried to replicate this. This works -> CREATE TABLE schema."table"
(
    file_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE schema."table"
    OWNER to postgres;  -> insert into schema.table (file_name) values ('my_ref_file_121323_1562070973_0.dmp'); The ONLY way I got this to fail was using     file_name character varying(100)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default"

Comment: Ref https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html -> SQL defines two primary character types: character varying(n) and character(n), where n is a positive integer. Both of these types can store strings up to n characters (not bytes) in length. An attempt to store a longer string into a column of these types will result in an error, unless the excess characters are all spaces, in which case the string will be truncated to the maximum length

Comment: Just to keep my reply simple. I could not replicate your problem. In fact the pseudo code above wored fine for me when I tested it on postgres (PostgreSQL) 10.8 using psql and pgadmin. All the best